# Typescript deep Pick by key without specifying a path

Tags: javascript, typescript, types

Let's say I've this type

```js
type Form = {
  collateral: {
      id: "collateralField",
      default: "",
      deps: ["collateralToken", "borrowInput", "asd"],
      severities: {
          first: 'first',
          second: 'second'
      }
  },
  borrow: {
    id: "borrowField",
    name: "Borrow"
  },
}
```

I'd like to create a generic that takes the type `Form` and a string `Query`. It should return an union of all the values of the Queried keys.

```js
type IDs = DeepKeys<Form, "id">
// Expected: "collateralField" | "borrowField"
```

This is my progress

```js
type DeepKeys<T, Q> =
  T extends object 
    ? { [K in keyof T]: (K extends Q ? T[K] : never) | DeepKeys<T[K], Q> }[keyof T]
    : never;
```

[Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYg9gJwLZQLxQN4CgpQMZwA2hAhsBAiYQFyY64MCWAJrQEQHFkVUyMSFmbADT0GUZhABmJAK6Fg7EWIaSwAZ1oBtDkVLlKhACpwA1hAB2IqGwBGiBHADuASQthZwa2xLqhAXVFxXHUIADcKRmB%20TTpg4KlGBHVFKAByROTgNKD4hlCCC1Z0grgitJVcAF96Ktz7BEcnWmxxFnYGpr4BIVzcCxIkCHYAIQdnNlrRGqwsUEgoABEICDAAaQgQdQAeI2EoAEUAPjR6IygIAA9yIvUoOFsAKwg8YCgVAH5MKC01qEYLFBzCA4FIoEZ-LQABR-K43Zh3A5QL5GX7%20KC0CzhCgASigAB8lit1psdqi1oFDicqlpgaDwf4VJjsQgANyzObgaAuRZ3dDLVYbLbbeDIfZsFhsI5YAD0MqgAFFLpBXhBirouAZePxBGwCTZOs5urqgA)

It seems to loop into the array object and append some unnecessary stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You nearly got it.

The problem is that TypeScript is recurisively iterating over all keys, including those of arrays. That creates issues as there are unncecessary keys in your final type.

Here is a fix:

```
type DeepKeys<T, Q> = T extends object 
  ? {
    [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends (infer R)[]
      ? never
      : K extends Q 
        ? T[K]
        : DeepKeys<T[K], Q>
    }[keyof T]
  : never;
```

Just tested this out and seemed to work fine on the TS playground.

With this improved version, you can do the following

```
type IDs = DeepKeys<Form, "id">;
```